# Why won't Hibernate 4's reverse engineering tool create relational annotations for entity classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc, reverse-engineering

I have been having a lot of difficulties trying to get Hibernate 4 to reverse engineer entity classes from my database schema. My database is actually a Derby database, but after reading around, I've heard that Derby may have issues with hibernate reverse-engineering, so I decided I was going to generate the entities with a MySQL database connection, but use the generated entities on my Derby connection (if that makes any sense).

I have SpringToolsSuite with JBoss's Hibernate plugins installed. I went to the database development perspective and created a data source that links to MySQL successfully. I can explore the tables just fine from inside STS/Eclipse. Then I went to the Hibernate perspective and set up a console configuration. Again, this appears to have been successful, and from the Hibernate perspective I can browse the tables and see the column definitions for the tables of my database just fine. I then go to the Hibernate Code Generation Configurations dialog to create a new configuration. I check "Reverse Engineer from JDBC Connection" and check all 4 of the options that become enabled. (I can't include images because my reputation is too low at the moment, so sorry if this isn't entirely clear)

Reverse engineer does work with these settings and does a lot of my task for me, but one major problem is that the entities being created do not have their foreign keys annotated correctly. For example, if I have Foo and one of Foo's columns is a foreign key to Bar, I would expect to see something like this in Foo's entity class:

```
...
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "barid", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
@ForeignKey(name="FK_BarID")
private Bar bar;
...
```

But what I get is much less useful:

```
...
@Column(name = "barid")
@NotNull
private Integer barid;
...
```

For now, I have decided to see if I can get the reverse-engineering features of Hibernate 4 to work with a smaller schema than the one I am actually trying to use. Preferably one that someone has reported as working. After googling around I have found someone with the exact same issue as the one that I am having (though his solution doesn't work for my case) a small example schema online:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?99864-Relationships-and-MySQL-domain-reverse-engineering

I had to change his schema slightly because the InnoBD engine in my version of MySQL wasn't happy with the foreign keys only being int, while the primary key they were referencing was a bigint. So I am using the following schema:

```
create table folder (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table language (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(30),
    code varchar(3),
    primary key (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table document (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    folderId bigint not null,
    title varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (folderId) REFERENCES folder(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table page (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    version int not null default 1,
    documentId bigint not null,
    languageId bigint not null default 1,
    fileName varchar(100),
    primary key (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (documentId) REFERENCES document(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (languageId) REFERENCES language(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have checked and verified that InnoDB is active and being used (using the SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME = 'TableName'; command) but this doesn't solve the issue as the link implies. I think I can get my schema to work fine if I can at least get this basic schema to do what I want, but after hours of trying I can't seem to make it recognize foreign keys for any schema. Is there a step that I am missing? Thanks.